# Screen resolution stuck at 1024x768

Tags: intel-graphics, display-resolution

I just updated from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04 and have an issue regarding the screen resolution. I have Intel integrated gfx chip and my monitor supports resolutions larger than 1024x768. (in 10.10 I've been using 1280x1024) But as soon as I upgraded, I'm stuck with 1024x768 resolution and seems I can't change it.  running

```
xrandr
```

In terminal yields the following results,

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x800       58.1 +
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       59.9 +
   1360x768       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     72.0     70.1     60.0* 
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
  1280x1024_60.00 (0xce)  109.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.7KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock   59.9Hz
```

What maybe the problem? Is it a bug? What kind of steps I should take in order to get a higher resolution? (changing xorg.conf maybe?) Any insight is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Screenshot after running

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1360x768
```

As you can see, side bar is not completely visible and Ubuntu logo at the task bar is missing. Also when you open an application, the Task bar of the application (where it should go to the top panel) is missing as well..

Comment: I keep coming back to this question over and over, sigh...

Comment: There is a useful answer for a similar question here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/890839/how-can-i-change-resolution-using-xrandr/1049868#1049868

Comment: There is a useful answer for a similar question here : [How can I change resolution using `xrandr` ?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049868/844010)

Comment: A detailed procedure on how to solve this problem is available [here](https://www.overwriteit.com/linux-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768-solution/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved the problem by running:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1366x768
```

I also added new modes to the change resolution drop down by using,

```
xrandr --newmode "mode line"
```

Where `mode line` replaces the supported resolutions. You can find the supported resolutions by running:

```
xrandr
```

Currently, it's working all right.

Comment: Hey Dananjaya do you maybe have an idea how to solve https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074324/hp-350-g2-vga-does-only-shows-1024x768 ? I am lost

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and I seem to have fixed it with the following.

[I found this thread from the ubuntuforums.org useful](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1730136).

1) If you need 1280x1024 (what I needed):

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60_new" 138.54 1280 1368 1504 1728 1024 1025 1028 1069 -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60_new
```

2) If you need 1440x900 (that's what the guy used, should work)

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.47  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1440x900_60.00
```

The only problem with this is that the resolution disappears after a restart and a message says could not apply the stored configuration for monitors. You can write a startup script though.

Answer (score 3):

To run at startup add the xrandr commands in `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` just before "initctl ..."
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

For my Dell 2711 I ran these two lines:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00" 193.25 1920 2056 2256 2592 1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "1920x1200_60.00"
```

(Not sure why it thinks I'm connected to HDMI, when it is actually connected to Display Port via DVI converter, perhaps that's why it's confused about the resolution options.)

Comment: what are all those imagic xrandr numbers?  And why would my desktop suddenly have decided it doesn't know the size of my monitor anyway?

Answer (score 2):

**Applications > Monitors**
[image]

Click the drop-dowm menu named **Resolution** and choose one that suits

Then click **Apply**

Then click **Close**.

Comment: I did earlier and the maximum resolution I could get was 1024x768 (4:3). However after I ran xrandr --addmode VGA1 1360x728 in the terminal a new resolution is added to the drop down. But when I set it, the side bar get all mixed up. (Please see the screenshot in the question)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the monitor cable wasn't plugged in properly.  This stopped Linux from querying the monitor properly!

Detect monitors would not work and only one resolution available.

Comment: Although it may be naive, I found out that my cable was the problem of my resolution after reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I tryied many methods and nothing wrks perfectly unitil I read the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution)
here wheat I did

```
cvt 1280 720 60
    # 1280x720 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.92M9) hsync: 44.77 kHz; pclk: 74.50 MHz
    Modeline "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode  "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1280x720_60.00
```