# Resolution set too low on startup, solutions do not work

Tags: 11.04, startup, gdm, resolution

After installing natty, my resolution is being set to 1024x768 instead of the proper 1368x768. The Monitors program doesn't allow me to set my resolution higher. I looked around for a solution, and I found instructions on using xrandr to set a new resolution:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768
```

This worked (but it broke the top Unity panel). Now I need to find a way to automatically start the xrandr commands on boot. I edited /etc/gdm/Init/Default and ~/.xprofile, but neither worked.

What do I do? Can I stop the problem from happening in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

This generally happens when the monitor doesn't report it's resolution correctly.

As you've found out, at runtime you can use the `xrandr` tool to add a correct mode and then switch to it.  To make this permanent, you can edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf and add that mode as the preferred mode.  I find the [Debian XSF XRandR howto](http://wiki.debian.org/XStrikeForce/HowToRandR12) a good guide for editing XRandR settings in xorg.conf.

Comment: I don't have an xorg.conf, and I'm still not sure what exactly should I do. I followed some instructions elsewhere and tried generating one with `sudo X -configure`, but that didn't work. What should I do now? Sorry if I'm being dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` ?

You can find many tutorials out there that explain how to add your own screen resolution in that file :

- [here is a link to the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/xorg.conf).
- and [this is a forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=83973) telling you what to do more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and solved it after reading this [document](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution). Also you might want to check the question I posted at askubuntu.com and it's answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768).