# Could not apply stored configuration for monitors

Tags: 11.04, resolution

Well this happened when I upgraded to Natty. Not only seems I can't change my resolution to higher than 1024x768 but it appears at the left and using only 70% of the monitor's width.

[image: Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors]

I tried logging in but in ubuntu classic mode, and i was able to change it, but that trick did not work anymore. (May this be a compiz problem?)

Anyways, here is my /var/log/Xorg.0.log http://pastebin.com/Ew4wwLab

and `lspci -nn | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a2] (rev 03)
```

I tried using xrandr for adding manually a resolution of 1280x1768 but without luck. Here is the xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*+
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x1024 (0xc6)  109.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.7KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock   59.9Hz
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, after some troubleshooting, connected the laptop to a second display and found that ubuntu is working fine. So it was a hardware problem in my Vaio laptop's screen.

Comment: Does [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37411) solve your issue?

Comment: hi @MarcoCeppi thanks for your interest. Here is what im getting [http://pastebin.com/j2Ukfytv](http://pastebin.com/j2Ukfytv). Any idea of what that error is?

Comment: Have you tried using `_` instead of `-`? Also, have you tried adding it without the `-new` at all and just the resolution?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Yes, but with the same result :(

Comment: Also noticed that when booting the motherboard splash screen and the BIOS are not being displayed... I think that is the problem.

Comment: Seems related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/67337/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-monitor-error

Answer (score 14):

Try to delete the file

```
~/.config/monitors.xml
```

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for you answer. I deleted it but without luck... Any tip?

Comment: Doing this solved my issue in 3 chances I had. 2 with 2 TVs and one with a video beam.

Comment: Thanks, this got rid of the error message for me! FYI though I got the error on every system start, it wasn't actually affecting anything, just an annoyance.

Comment: Had same problem, this fixes it :)