# Changing the resolution to 1440x900

Tags: 11.04, xorg, resolution, xrandr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen resolution stuck at 1024x768](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768)

The output of "xrandr"

```
yasith@vostro:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then I ran,

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

To create a new mode. Then when I try to set that mode to LVDS1 using the following command I get an error.

```
yasith@vostro:~$ xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1440x900_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.