# Display problem with Vizio HDTV

Tags: display

I just installed Ubuntu in my 4 year old machine and I'm having a display problem with my Vizio HDTV, it seems the screen is offset since the right/lower corner of the unity desktop is not aligned with the lower right corner of the display. I have to go with the mouse outside to the left of the screen in order to activate the left panel menu buttons. I used to be able to use this Vizio flat screen HDTV with Windows with this same computer.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Answered by OP in a comment:*

> After checking the screen resolution, I realized I had the option to
>   change position and horizontal size of the display in the TV and that
>   fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the screen resolution or the detecting the screen under system settings/displays. Try changing the resolution and meddling with it. Sorry but this is the only answer I can provide, i don't have a Vizio HDTV.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! After checking the screen resolution, I realized I had the option to change position and horizontal size of the display in the TV and that fixed the problem. Now I have the problem that the options in the display resolution provided under Unity's display settings seem to be not adequate for my TV. I haven't been able to find a resolution that will display photos in the right aspect ratio and utilizing teh widescreen format 16:9. Is ther a way to get a resolution with more than 1024 pixels horizontally and with 16:9 aspect ratio?

Comment: @user33786 I am adding a part of your answer as a Community-wiki answer as it seems to have solved your problem. About the screen resolution question, you can take a look at [Screen resolution stuck at 1024x768](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768) or post a new question if it doesn't help you. Thanks :)