# Now only boots with VGA graphics

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, intel

On boot I can only configure a max resolution of 1024x768 now after booting this morning. I ended up reinstalling ubuntu 11.10 and still am limited to this as the max resolution. The display is detected as `unknown`.

My graphics are on chip Intel 2500K (Intel HD 3000 graphics), the monitor is a Dell 2209W. The reinstalled system has been updated to the latest packages (there's no more updates to apply).

All has been fine until I updated the repositories last night.

Other than that there's nothing really unique about my system.

```
slioch@slioch-desktop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you tried [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/37705/18612) from a [related question](http://askubuntu.com/q/37411/18612)? If that doesn't work for you, can you go into the Software Center, go into the History section and click the Updates button, then list which packages were updated between your last known working configuration and now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.

```
~$ lspci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Fixed this way. First calculate vesa cvt:

```
~$ cvt 1280 720 
# 1280x720 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.92M9) hsync: 44.77 kHz; pclk: 74.50 MHz
Modeline "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
```

then set xrandr:

```
~$ xrandr --newmode 1280x720_60.00 74.50 1280 1344 1472 1664 720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x720_60.00
```