# I can't set my resolution higher than 1024x768 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution

I'm an Nvidia GT 440 user.
I can already click on the 1280x1024 option in monitors but as shown in the image below it outputs an error.
The message says:The virtual size required doesn't fit the available one,plus it says the maximum size is 1024x768
I tried many things and i ended thinking that the problem could probably be the EDID info,so I installed the package read-edid.
When i type

> sudo get-edid | parse-edid

it prints this http://pastebin.com/GSnaJDnn

If more explanation is needed I'll post it as fast as i can

Comment: Have you tried with the answers in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/37411/62483)?

Comment: this is the output of "xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60_new"

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
And in the logfile of Xorg I have encountered this warning Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-1 (Which is odd because my monitor is a TFT)

Comment: Please add the output of the following to your Question: `sudo lshw -numeric -c video`, `lsmod`, `xrandr -q`. In particular I'm wondering what driver is being used in your system to run your graphics.

Comment: This is the output of the commands http://pastebin.com/r22w3ue5

Comment: In Additional drivers says i'm using now the current-updates version (I recently uninstalled nvidia-current because it doesn't started the graphical environment)  
P.S:sorry for double-posting