# Monitor Resolution problems after last update

Tags: updates, resolution, monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol)
>   [Screen resolution stuck at 1024x768](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768)

I don't know if there is already a question like that but after my last update (Update manager) when i logged in Ubuntu my resolution was set to 1024/768 and there is no option at displays to change it to another.when i use  the command  -> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current the output at terminal is that :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-current is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I am noob with Ubuntu and i would like some help to fix this problem. 
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: On a console type `glxinfo | grep direct` add the output to your question

Comment: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

Comment: check this question 

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

remove the xorg config file & reboot.

Type in

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.back`.

Then reboot the system `sudo reboot now`

If that doesn't solve the problem or cause any other thing, revert back using

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: the answer at the first command:   mv: cannot stat `/etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: and something else, when i try to open nvidia x server settings i get the message :    You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.

Comment: execute `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, try to change resolution and reboot.

Comment: The output of xrandr:                                             xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   1680x1050_60.00   60.0  
  1680x105_60.00 (0x73)  146.2MHz
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz

Comment: And the output of command xrandr --addmode default 1680x1050_60.00                       ekeinos@ekeinos-OEM:~$ xrandr --addmode default 1680x1050_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default