# resolution problem in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: display-resolution

hello guys i installed ubuntu 13.10 on my dell optipex 760 with a fujitsu 1280x1024 resolution lcd but when i installed ubuntu 13.10 my resolution was stuck to 1024x768. i followed the instruction on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768)

but when i used xrandr it gave me the resolution 5:3 1280x1024 wheras my lcd is **4:3** 1280x1024 can anyone please suggest a solution for this problem.

sorry  my english is bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Resolution Ubuntu 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/custom-resolution-ubuntu-13-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the answer. I typed in the terminal `cvt 1280 1024` and it just gave me the modeline.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to add an extra line, please try on following:

i.e:

`xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync`

`xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00`

`xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_60.00`

Regards

Comment: thanks for the info but i need the xrandr to set my sesolution 1280x1024 and 4:3 i dont know the  values to set i.e ( <hdisp> <hsync-start> <hsync-end> <htotal> <vdisp> <vsync-start> <vsync-end> <vtotal> ) for 1280x1024 4:3 screen