# Can't find optimal screen resolution

Tags: resolution, screen

Since a week I am a ubuntu user. Switched from windows since my paid xp license is not supported anymore.
Iḿ really satisfied about ubuntu, works perfectly!

Just one small problem, that's my screen resolution. I'm using a Iiyama ProLite E1902WSV monitor on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

When I put the code `xrandr` in the terminal, I get the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And now the problem starts, becouse the optimal screen resolution for my Iiyama isn't in this list. I've looked around on the internet and the best resolution should  be 1440x900 ([source](http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/160825/iiyama-prolite-e1902wsv-b1-zwart.html))

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

:::EDIT:::

After the solution from  Sylvain Pineau I started my computer this morning and got the following message.

```
none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 143
CRTC 143: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 143: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 143: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 143: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 143: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 143: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 143: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 143: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 143: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 143: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 144
CRTC 144: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 144: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 144: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 144: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 144: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 144: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 144: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 144: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 144: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 144: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1440x900@60Hz (pass 1)
```

Is there a solution to this aswell? I have the same screen resolution as in the beginning 1024x768 (4:3) again...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen resolution stuck at 1024x768](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768)

Comment: In the case you redirecting to is the resolution he needs at least in the xrandr result. In my case I can't find the resolution of my monitor at all in that result. I need the 1440x900 and the biggest available in the xrandr is 1024x768 (not even widescreen)

Comment: Did you try `xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.47  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync` and `xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900_60.00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try first to define a VIRTUAL1 display:

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00" 106.47 1440 1520 1672 1904 900 901 904 932 -HSync +Vsync
```

And use it to set the profile of **VGA-1**:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900_60.00
```

Comment: Wonderfull!! This worked perfectly!
Thank you very much!!

Comment: I wass to early to be happy... See my edit in the first post (is to long for comment)

Comment: Please check this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent) to store your new settings permanently.

Comment: I may be to stupid to imagine, but I still can't fix it. When I change the lightdm.conf file it says that I can not save it becouse it's a read-only file.

Comment: Indeed, this file belongs to the system. You to use `sudo gedit your_file` to edit and save such files.

Comment: I need 15 reputation points to do that, sorry