# Start ubuntu with xrandr generated screen resolution

Tags: resolution, lightdm, xrandr

First of all, sorry for starting a new question. I couldn't see the forest thrue all the trees anymore is what we would say here in holland.

It started with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438956/cant-find-optimal-screen-resolution) where I didn't know how to switch to my optimal screen resolution. Sylvain Pineau helped me out with the solution to use the xrandr code in the terminal. That worked out, but i fail to make it go to that resolution (1440x900) when my computer start. Even the redirection to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent) didn't help me out. The fourth answer on that page did look similar to what I had done with the xrandr code. But when I have made the changes to lightdm.conf and want to save it, it says that it is a read only file wich I can't overwrite.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

:::EDIT:::

I used this answer, becouse it seemed the most simple solution. I just don't understand the script wich is used in the terminal yet.
But this answer below said that I needed to change the lightdm.conf

> I've had a similar problem with my laptop as above, and I wanted to
>   add something to the conversation. If you don't care about the login
>   resolution (I don't), but want the actual workspace to be the right
>   resolution, you can add your monitor information to LightDM but not
>   turn on full resolution until you login.
>
> I just added the following script for my monitor in a file:
>   lighdmxrandr
>
> xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900
>   903 909 934 -hsync +vsync xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00
>
> then I call it in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
>
> display-setup-script=/usr/bin/lightdmxrandr
>
> Once I login I can setup my monitor in Displays and it works, even
>   after I re-log (used to give me a big ugly error).

Comment: Post your xorg.conf that you are trying to use..

Comment: I've add the answer from the redirected page in a quote in my first post. Itś too long for in this commend field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I found out how to use a xrandr code automaticly when ubuntu starts.

1. Open dash and type "startup"
2. Open Startup Applications
3. Click on "add" to add the code
4. Fill in the form and click add

Done

Comment: This was the easiest solution for me.