# Can't change screen resolution more than 1024x768, even thought untill yesterday it was working fine on larger resolutions

Tags: ati, xorg, resolution

I need some help fixing my resolution. It's stuck at 1024x768, but yesterday it was working well on 1280x1024. I'm using ATI HD2600, and I know that XUbuntu has some problems with ATI.I want to add 1280x1024 resolution.

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DIN disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)  
DVI-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       60.0*     
800x600        60.3     56.2     
848x480        60.0      
640x480        59.9
```

xorg.conf is also missing from it's location. Also I tried adding:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024
xrandr --addmode LVDS 1280x1024
```

and it didn't work either. I tried installing Catalyst from AMD but still no luck with it. I'm a noob on Ubuntu, and I can't find any solutions to this, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, for anyone that's stucked like I was for now, and have the same output for `xrandr`, here's the solution:

> xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1280 1024 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1280x1024/')
>   xrandr --addmode DVI-1 1280x1024

After that you can change the resolution by going to display

Answer (score 0):

Does the Display / Screen / Monitors settings page (whatever it's called in your DE) have any options to change resolution, & do they work?

And according to `xrandr` there you should have 4 resolutions available, have you tried changing it with `xrandr`, maybe with `xrandr -s 800x600` or whichever you want, with/without `-r 60`?

For a different mode, not listed in `xrandr` yet, first try:

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-1 1280x1024
```

I'm not sure, but I think to add the new mode permanently you'll have to use xrandr's `--newmode` that uses "ModeLine syntax for xorg.conf".
Then:

```
xrandr -s 1280x1024
```

[See this Q & A for more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768) But in that one `xrandr` already lists the wanted resolution, just no refresh rate. In this case, xrandr doesn't list 1280x1024 at all, so it refuses to `--addmode` for it...

Maybe it is a driver issue, could try updating graphic drivers, any updates to packages waiting? (`apt-get update` or upgrade all packages with `apt-get upgrade`) Or checked "Driver Manager" or "Additional Drivers" (or whatever it's called now) for adding hardware drivers? Some AMD graphics use the `fglrx` package, but I'm not sure for yours.

Comment: Sorry for didn't mentioning.I want to add a 1280x1024 resolution

Comment: edited more addmode

Comment: xrandr: cannot find mode "1280x1024", any suggestions?

Comment: Does the monitor even support 1280x1024, it works in windows & everything? And in case the monitor or driver just won't cooperate, did the monitor change to any other resolutions like 800x600? with `xrandr -s 800x600`?

Comment: yea, sice today, I was running 1280x1240, and after closing my pc, the max resolution available it's 1024x768.And yes, `xrandr -s 800x600` is working

Comment: Ok, so at least it's not "stuck" in 1024x768. How about `xrandr --addmode DVI-1 "1280x1024_60.00"` or `xrandr --addmode "DVI-1 1280x1024_60.00"` or `xrandr --addmode "DVI-1" "1280x1024_60.00"` (in case quoting)

Comment: still no luck.`xrandr: cannot find mode "1280x1024_60.00"`

Comment: hmmm, added a more detailed related Q. And since you can change the resolution, it's not stuck, you could edit your Q to reflect/clarify?

Comment: I saw these question, but nothing from there didn't worked for me.I will edit my question, and thank you for your time.I really appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19495/discussion-between-marian-ioan-and-xen2050).

Comment: I think I see why the --addmode wouldn't work, updated A. Next idea: updated packages (`apt-get update` or upgrade all packages with `apt-get upgrade`) or additional drivers (should be in start menu/programs, something like driver... or additional drivers...). I had a similar problem with resolutions, I think an update (or maybe a different linux) helped. You're welcome. Got to run, good luck!