# How can I change resolution using xrandr?

Tags: command-line, display-resolution, monitor

I have a dual monitor setup. 2nd monitor has a VGA connection. Resolution 1366x768 not found in display settings or `randr`. How do I add resolution 1366x768 to output.  I have tried this:

```
VGA-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+190 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

Did  `xrandr -s 1366x768`:

```
Size 1366x768 not found in available modes
```

And `xrandr --output vga-0 --mode 1366x768`:

```
warning: output vga-0 not found; ignoring
```

Comment: *Size 1366x768 not found in available modes* - You can only set it to 1024x768,  800x600, 
   848x480    ,      
   640x480,

Comment: Try `xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1366x768` instead

Comment: thank you. It can be changed as I did about 2 years ago but cannot remember exactly how.   Unfortunately this did not work xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1366x768  but thanks for trying.

Comment: Check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768?rq=1), it might help

Answer (score 6):

> And `xrandr --output vga-0 --mode 1366x768:`
>   `warning: output vga-0 not found; ignoring`

Terminals are case sensitive(may not be for windows **BUT**), `vga-0` is not equal to `VGA-0` and hence the problem.

---

> Did  `xrandr -s 1366x768`:
>   `Size 1366x768 not found in available modes`

You can create a custom screen resolution when not listed and your display supports it. Check this ubuntu handbook guide :
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/

If you want to follow the part

> **IMPORTANT**: To make Ubuntu remember the new created screen resolution
>   at next start, you have to edit the `.profile` via command:

Then to avoid the `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` error after each login, you might follow a working answer of this StackOverflow Question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error