# Screen resolution stuck at 1024 x768 and no HDMI signal

Tags: 14.04, display, dell, hdmi, display-resolution

I'm aware there are a few versions of this question running around but I've tried following various instructions and can't seem to get a resolution.

Right, here we go. I recently ran a few updates and since rebooting I am stuck at 1024x768 resolution, and have no HDMI output.
I'm running a Dell Inspiron 15-3552 on LTS 14.04. I'm aware that this is slightly lacking in detail, I'm quite clueless as to what is going on at this point so not sure what else to share but will take any and all instructions!

Comment: so the resolution under display in system settings is having only one option (1024*768)?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: see if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/37705/796752) is helpful. This is for older version (11.04)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that again and sadly no joy.