# Ubuntu 16.04 Resolution stuck at 1024 x 768

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I tried the posts in [Screen resolution stuck at 1024x768](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768) but they didn't seem to help.

In my display settings, I am unable to see any other resolution besides 1024 x 768.

The output of `xrandr` is

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

and the output for `xrandr -q`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
  1280x1024 (0x2d7) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
```

I am connected via a display port cable. Could someone please assist?

#Edit

Here is the request edit and output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
|Display'
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K2200] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM107GL [Quadro K2200]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
04:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Got it. Just edited it in.

Comment: Do you think the capability of the graphics card + monitor should be greater than 1024x768?

Comment: @wallyk Yes because I have gotten much higher resolution on this monitor before on the same machine last year (I rarely use this machine now). The monitor is an Elite Display E240q. I plugged this monitor into my mac just now  using an HDMI cable (my linux machine doesn't have an HDMIT port) and was able to get a lot higher resolution.

Comment: @wallyk My guess is something is outdated with my graphics driver. But I'm not sure how to diagnose that

Comment: Are you using `nomodeset` in `grub`. It looks like you do. Please add output of `cat /etc/default/grub`.